# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to make a blog using ReactJS and NextJS in VS Code I don't have any error but when I run it it shows in browser: " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') "

So this is the code

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import moment from 'moment';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { getSimilarPosts, getRecentPosts } from '../services';

const PostWidget = ({ categories, slug }) => {
  const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (slug) {
      getSimilarPosts(categories, slug).then((result) => {
        setRelatedPosts(result);
      });
    } else {
      getRecentPosts().then((result) => {
        setRelatedPosts(result);
      });
    }
  }, [slug])

  console.log(relatedPosts)

  return (
    <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg p-8 pb-12 mb-8">
      <h3 className="text-xl mb-8 font-semibold border-b pb-4">{slug ? 'Related Posts' : 'Recent Posts'}</h3>
      {relatedPosts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.title} className="flex items-center w-full mb-4">
          <div className="w-16 flex-none">
            <img
              alt={post.title}
              height="60px"
              width="60px"
              unoptimized
              className="align-middle rounded-full"
              src={post.featuredImage.url}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-grow ml-4">
            <p className="text-gray-500 font-xs">{moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}</p>
            <Link href={`/post/${post.slug}`} className="text-md" key={index}>{post.title}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostWidget;
```

And this is where the error is.

```
{relatedPosts.map((post) =>
```

Comment: `getSimilarPosts` or `getRecentPosts` probably return `undefined`, hence you need to check if `relatedPosts` is `undefined` prior to calling a method on it with `relatedPosts?.map()` (see [Optional chaining on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))

Answer (score 1):

use `?` make in this code:

```
{relatedPosts?.map((post) =>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Check **relatedPosts** has data before rendering map.
If not working please share **getSimilarPosts, getRecentPosts**

```
{
   relatedPosts && 
   relatedPosts.length > 0 &&
   relatedPosts.map((post) => (
      ...
   ))
}
```